# How to use str_replace on multi-dimensional arrays?

Tags: php, csv

I have a Csv File :

- mobile      Name    Pending Amt
- 9999999999  John    10
- 8888888888  Rita    21
- 9999988888  Tom     56
- 8888899999  Tony    8
- 7777777777  Zebra   100

I want to convert this file to an array to create multiple strings of messages.

```
// Parse the csv into array
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('metu2.csv')); 

// Remove first array as it is the Column Titles
array_shift($csv);

$message = "Dear [F1], Please pay Rs [F2] thanks"; // Declare message

// Loop thru each array and echo message
foreach($csv as $array) {
echo str_replace("[F1]","$array[1]", $message);
echo '<br>';
}

//Output:

// Dear John, Please pay Rs [F2] thanks
// Dear Rita, Please pay Rs [F2] thanks
// Dear Tom, Please pay Rs [F2] thanks
// Dear Tony, Please pay Rs [F2] thanks
// Dear Zebra, Please pay Rs [F2] thanks
```

How to replace [F2] at the same time?

Comment: I can't see your coding attempt in the question.  You are not meant to use SO as a free coding service.  Volunteers are meant to fix your code (which has an isolated issue), not manufacture new code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) to parse the csv file to array. You can use `array_map` with it

```
$message = "Dear %s, Please pay $ %d."; // Declare message

// Parse the csv into array
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('mobile.csv')); 

// Remove first array as it is the Column Titles
array_shift($csv);

// Loop thru each array and echo message
foreach($csv as $array) {
    echo sprintf($message, $array[1], $array[2]);
    echo '<br>';
}
```

If you're really working with [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). Change the foreach loop function to something like this

```
$message = "Dear [F1], Please pay Rs [F2] thanks"; // Message

foreach($csv as $array) {
    $search = array("[F1]", "[F2]"); // Strings to search
    $replace = array($array[1], $array[2]); // Values to place
    echo str_replace($search, $replace, $message); // str_replace function
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Search and replace arrays corresponds to it's respective index.

e.g. `$search[0]` is replaced with `$replace[0]`

Comment: If you want an associative array with the column titles as keys then insert the following between the array map and the array shift `array_walk($csv, function(&$a) use ($csv) {$a = array_combine($csv[0], $a);});`

Comment: Cool. Tried it just now. That's kinda helpful! Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks Erwin your code working fine, but how to do this if message is different everytime in textarea.For Eg - Hi #name# your amount is pending #amt# .

Comment: The easiest way would be what @Dam Fa suggested. Use `sprintf`. See edited answer

Comment: But Sir through this method values are not displaying. Now output is -Dear , Please pay $ .  , No values ? Previously it was working fine.

Comment: Changed specifiers for `sprintf()` to *%s* for string representation and *%d* for integer and as (signed) decimal number

Comment: Hi Erwin , I almost there please see my new code, How to also replace [F2] at the same time with $array[2]. Please Note : Every time message and CSV file will be different.

Comment: Please check edited answer. Using `str_replace()`

Comment: Hi erwin , i have new problem , this code showing me the same result from previously uploaded csv file , even after i uploaded new file it is showing me the same result from previous csv file

Comment: Hi @Erwin please check now with sample csv file - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539525/foreach-loop-showing-previous-array

Comment: @Erwin, I had just tested, code is not working if i have more than 10000 rows in csv file and when i edit the same file and delete 5000 rows , code will show the result for all 10000 rows not for 5000 rows, and thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

You would better use `sprintf` (http://php.net/manual/fr/function.sprintf.php) instead of str_replace.

You can do easily what you want with something like :

```
<?php
$message = "Dear %s, \n Please pay %d.";

if (($handle = fopen("your-file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, " ")) !== FALSE) {
       echo sprintf($message, $data[1], $data[2]) . "<br/>";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: I am unable to get particular column(Eg Name Column) as an array in csv file, $data[1] and $data[2]?

Comment: What is you "data separator" in your csv file ? And what is your "line separator" ?

Comment: I tried your code but its not working correctly. It is not showing values.Output is - Dear , Please pay 0.

Comment: Have you seen my previous questions ? Can you give more info about your csv separators ? Because in your question your separators seem to be "spaces", but if the answer of @Erwin works for you I guess your data separators are "comas" (,) ... Also, Have you tried a `var_dump($data);` before the "echo" just to check what is inside the $data array ? If there is your full line of text, so just replace `" "`  by `","` in the `fgetcsv` call.

Comment: Hello Dam Fa, I almost there please see my new code, How to also replace [F2] at the same time with $array[2]. Please Note : Every time message and CSV file will be different.

Comment: Hi @Dam Fa please check now - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539525/foreach-loop-showing-previous-array